# Regex that does not match any html tag

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I am really bad with regexps, what I want is a regexp that does not match any html tags (for user input validation).

What I want is negative of this:

```
<[^>]+>
```

What I currently have is

```
public class MessageViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"<[^>]+>", ErrorMessage = "No html tags allowed")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

but it does opposite of what I want - allows usernames only with html tags

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regular expressions cannot do "negative" matches.

But they can do "positive" matches and you can then throw out of the string everything that they have found.

---

Edit - after the question was updated, things became a little clearer. Try this:

```
public class MessageViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?!.*<[^>]+>).*", ErrorMessage = "No html tags allowed")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Explanation:

```
^            # start of string
(?!          # negative look-ahead (a position not followed by...)
  .*         #   anything
  <[^>]+>    #   something that looks like an HTML tag
)            # end look-ahead
.*           # match the remainder of the string
```

Comment: I am using a [RegularExpression] attribute in c# and I want to disallow user to input any html tags

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, but could not find a clear syntax to do. Regexes are the most coplex thing I came across so far

Comment: Instead of blacklisting things (like HTML tags), think about whitelisting. That's a lot more secure and much easier to maintain. `[RegularExpression(@"^[\p{L}\p{N}]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only letters and numbers. No spaces allowed.")]` See http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html for help selecting the proper Unicode character ranges. The non-Unicode version of this `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"`.

Comment: It seems to work with an inline s modifier. `^(?s)(?!.*<[^>]+>).*`

Comment: @Wesley Of course, that's the alternative. The .NET regex flavor supports that modifier, not all of them do.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old but I recently came across the same need, almost.

I wanted to allow ">" or "<" if it has a space before/after preventing the HTML to see it has tag.

Maybe it's not perfect but it did the job for me :

```
^((?!(<\S)|(\S>)).)*$
```

You can test it here : [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/o88bC6/2)

Comment: Given that there is already an accepted answer (from a long time ago), could you explain in which case your solution would be an interesting alternative, to help users make their choice.